# Google Site not getting indexed due to Page Redirect

Tags: google-search, google-sites

I have created a website using Google Sites. I have published using a custom domain (https://www.abilityalpha.com). It is not getting indexed by Google Search because of "Page Redirect" issue.

How can I solve this problem? I am not a techie. Any help will be wonderful.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]